# Creating two objects of the same classes from different imports made them look as different classes

Tags: python, oop, python-import

I have a the following file in Python:

- `SB/__init__.py`

  ```
  from .interval import *
  ```
- `SB/interval.py`

  ```
  class Interval:
      blablabla  # Do stuff with intervals
      def __eq__(self, other):
          # Do comparison
      def __lt__(self, other):
          # Do comparison
      def __le__(self, other):
          # Do comparison
      def __gt__(self, other):
          # Do comparison
      def __ge__(self, other):
          # Do comparison

  def interval_from_file(filename):
      blablabla  # Read the file, etc
      result = []
      for l in lines:
          fields = l.split('\t')
          ... # Validate the fields
          result.append(Interval(fields))
       return result
  ```

If I do `import SB` from an IPython shell or Jupyter and I load some data with `SB.interval_from_file`, I get a list of Interval objects. But, if I then manually create an Interval object with `SB.Interval`, I cannot compare that object with any other from the list. I get instead

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Interval' and 'Interval'`

Any idea what's going on?

**edit**: If I print the type of the objects, the ones in the list (so from `SB.interval_from_file` have the type `SB.interval.Interval` whereas the object created in the IPython shell with `SB.Interval` is of type `interval.Interval`. Is that behavior expected?

Comment: Maybe your pythonpath is including both SB and its parent directory (make sure you include just the appropriate directory).

Comment: You're right, both `SB` and `interval` were included. That works fine now! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Added my comment as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your pythonpath is including both SB and its parent directory.

Make sure you include just the appropriate directory.